# int conversion -- gives me weird numbers

Tags: c++

I'm new to the programming world and C++ is already losing me. I had these lines in my program

```
pennies=(amount-nickels*.05)/.01;
```

**amount** is a `double`, while and **nickels** are `int`.

The program returns the right value when **pennies** is a `double` but things are a little off (off by 1 most of the time) whenever **pennies** is an `int`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: When you store the result in `pennies`, the value get's truncated instead of rounded. Try `int pennies = 1.9; std::cout << pennies;` to see for yourself.

Comment: I'm sure people can help with an issue like this, but in the future you should include example data so that we know what you mean by "off" (for example "When `amount` is 10 and `nickels` is 5 I expect the result to be 12 but it is 13.")

Comment: I'd recommend representing money as integer numbers of pennies to avoid rounding errors and numerical imprecision, at least to start with. Leave tackling those hard problems until you need sub-penny amounts :)

Comment: Oh, also it's not just a C++ problem; this is the kind of problem you'll face with floating point numbers in any language.

Comment: Never represent money as floating point values!

Comment: @SpongeBobFan It depends on what you're doing.  We use `double` almost everywhere for monetary values.  I'd like to see you do Monte Carlo simulations for future value using a decimal class.

Answer (score 8):

This is happening because the value is truncated thus losing the decimal precision.

For integers:

```
int i;
i = 1.1  //stores 1 in i
i = 1.2  //stores 1 in i
i = 1.3  //stores 1 in i
i = 1.4  //stores 1 in i
i = 1.5  //stores 1 in i
i = 1.6  //stores 1 in i
i = 1.7  //stores 1 in i
i = 1.8  //stores 1 in i
i = 1.9  //stores 1 in i
i = 1.999999 //stores 1 in i
```

I would suggest you to change your expression to:

```
pennies=amount*100-nickels*5;
```

Comment: No, this is happening because the value *isn't* rounded. As jrok mentioned in the comments on the question, the value gets truncated.

Comment: It could also be because of numerical imprecision in the intermediate calculations, not just rounding of the final result.

Comment: @BenHymers It could be because `amount` and `nickels` are already imprecise, although I would imagine (hope) that `nickels` has an integral value, which can be represented exactly (assuming the number of nickels is less than around 9e15---probably a safe assumption, since that many nickels would weigh something like 45 billion tons, making it unlikely that anyone would be carrying them around in their pocket).

Comment: Well now you're just being silly :) (also `nickels` is an `int`)

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, the problem is because `0.1` and
`0.05` don't have an exact representations in machine floating
point.  The simplest solution here is to simply round the
results, instead of truncating:

```
pennies = round( (amount - nickels * 0.05) / 0.01 );
```

A better solution in this particular case (where you are dealing
with coins) is simply to use integers everywhere, and do
everything in terms of cents, rather than dollars.  This stops
working (or requires some very complex programming) very quickly
however: even things like calculating VAT or sales tax cause
problems.  For such cases, there are two possible solutions:

- Continue using `double`, rounding as necessary.  This is the
  simplest and most general solution.  Be aware, however, that
  when using it, rounding is done on *binary* values, and it may
  in some cases differ from what you would get with rounding
  decimal values.  The difference should be small enough that it
  won't matter for every day use, but most countries have laws
  specifying how such values must be rounded, and those rounding
  rules are always specified in decimal.  Which means that this
  solution cannot be used in cases where legal requirements hold
  (e.g calculating sales tax, corporate bookkeeping, etc.).
- Use some sort of decimal class.  There are a number available
  on the network.  This will result in slower execution times.
  (Typically, who cares.  You'll get the results in 100
  microseconds, rather than 10.  But there are exceptions; e.g.
  when doing Monte Carlo simulations.)

Also, you must be aware when large values are involved.  For
your personal finances, it's almost certainly irrelevant, but
`int` does have a maximum value, and there is a point where
`double` can no longer represent integer values correctly.

Of course, if this is just an exercise to help in learning C++,
just use `round` or integers, and don't worry too much about the
rest.

And as for your comment "C++ is already losing me": this has
nothing to do with C++ per se.  You'd encounter exactly the same
issues in (almost) any programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You compute a float number on the right part of the expression, but then you try to store a double in an int value. When you do this, the fractional part is lost.

Answer (score 1):

```
                   pennies=(amount-nickels*.05)/.01;
```

**In the above expression, the numerator and denominator arithmetic occurs in double** because of the variable amount(which is double)-**Implicit Conversion happens here**. At the end if pennies is double the computed result will get stored in pennies, if it is int, fractional part of the computed result will be lost. *The intermediate compution will always happens in double, and it doesn't depends upon pennies type anyway.*

**Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

   int a ;

   double c,d=10.55555;

   a =  c=  (d+ 10*.5)/0.5 ;
   printf("%f : %d/n",c,a);
   return 0;
}
```

The output is:

**31.111100 : 31**

Here first 10 is promoted to float then 10*.5 will get evaluated, which will get promoted to double because of addition with a double value, then the denominator also converted to double as numerator is double, hence the compution occurs in double format only.